# Function that checks if arg1 is an instance of arg2, like isInstanceOf(a,A) in Scala

Tags: class, scala, reflection

I've been trying to come up with a function that checks wether an argument is of a type given at runtime.

Consider function `is` (short for "is of class") in the following example:

```
    object TestClass {
        abstract class P()
        case class A() extends P
        case class B() extends P
        // ...
        case class Z() extends P

        def is[VALUE,TYPE](value:VALUE, T:TYPE): Boolean = {
            value match {
                case T => true
                case _ => false
            }
        }

        def main(args: Array[String]) {
            val a = new A()
            val b = new B()

            println(a.isInstanceOf[A]) // true
            println(is(a, A)) // false
            println(is(b, B)) // false
        }
    }
```

I've read about ClassTag and getClass, but I'm new to Scala and cannot apply them correctly, it seems. How should `is` be implemented for all `println`-lines to return `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking against the *value* `T`, which will be the *companion object* of `A` or `B` - it might be easier to understand what's going on if you use non-case classes.

After correcting the code you'll find it always returns true, with a warning that the pattern is unchecked due to erasure:

```
def is[TYPE](value: Any): Boolean = value match {
  case t: TYPE => true
  case _ => false
}
```

The usual way around this is by using a `ClassTag` as a pattern:

```
def is[TYPE](value: Any)(implicit tag: ClassTag[TYPE]): Boolean = value match {
  case tag(_) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Note that this will only match the runtime, erased class, so you will get surprising answers for generic types:

```
is[List[Int]](List("abc")) //true
```

If you want a more general solution you may want to look at [Shapeless type-safe extractors](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#type-safe-cast)